# Detecting datatype of each column in javascript prepending

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix, traversal, prepend

I am working on an algorithm that detect the datatype of each column and prepend it to the top of the list. So I have say 2D matrix and 
1) I need to detect the datatype of each element 
2) Count the sum of each type of matrix column wise 
3) Get the maximum of each type column wise
4) Prepend the type from 3 at the top of respective column

So here is the example
[image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

1) For first, I know 2 techniques. i.e via jquery

```
         $.each(row, function (index,item) {
         alert(typeof(item)); //result is object instead of specific type
```

2) matrix traversing

```
       for (var i=0;i<data[i].length;i++) {
       for (var j=0;j<data1.length;j++) {    
       var r = data1[j][i];
       if(isFinite(r) == true && )
       numeric++ ;
        else {str++;}
```

I know this is not the best method, but it is working for me well in giving number of string and numeric types

I know there is a an unshift() that prepend data at the top of a list..But, still not sure how will it work for me.

Any help and suggestions.

Comment: I feel your description is not enough to understand what you want to do perfectly. Please attach more example matrix and result array you wish to get.

Comment: There is a `splice` function that you can remove/add items on a specific index. **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

Comment: I do not get your data vs result. What is the 50 and 5 in each column? Are they part of the data? What do you mean by count the sum of each data type? Do you mean count number of items in each column? Where is maximum etc. in your *"Resultant array"*?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your end goal is. One would likely say a column is *string* if *any* of the values is a string, and number only if *all* items are numbers.

Be careful with polluting global space with variables. Usually you would confine then to closed scopes.

*More* strings or *more* numbers also have to account for cases where the count is equal. E.g. five numbers and five strings.

The following could be a start:

```
// Should be expanded to fully meet needs.
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(n + 0) /* && varius */;
}

// Count types of data in column.
// Return array with one object for each column.
function arrTypeStat(ar) {
    var type = [], i, j;
    // Loop by column
    for (i = 0; i < ar[0].length; ++i) {
        // Type-stats for column 'i'
        type[i] = {num: 0, str: 0};
        // Loop rows for current column.
        for (j = 1; j < ar.length; ++j) {
            if (isNumber(ar[j][i]))
                ++type[i].num;
            else
                ++type[i].str;
        }
    }
    return type;
}

// Add a row after header with value equal to 'num' or 'str' depending
// on which type is most frequent. Favoring string if count is equal.
function arrAddColType(ar) {
    var type = arrTypeStat(ar);
    // Add new array as second item in 'ar'
    // as in: add a new (empty) row. This is the row to be filled
    // with data types.
    ar.splice(1, 0, []);
    // Note:
    // Favour string over number if count is equal.
    for (i = 0; i < type.length; ++i) {
        ar[1][i] = type[i].num > type[i].str ? 'num' : 'str';
    }
    return ar;
}
```

---

[Sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/sG4ND/) Use console, <kbd>F12</kbd>, to view result of test. Note that in this sample the numbers are represented both as quoted and un-quoted.

```
// Sample array.
var arrTest = [
    ['album','artist','price'],
    [50,5,'50'],    
    [5,5,'5'],
    ['Lateralus', 'Tool', '13'],
    ['Ænima','Tool','12'],
    ['10,000 days','Tool',14]
];

// Test
var test = arrAddColType(arrTest);

// Log
console.log(
    JSON.stringify(test)
    .replace(/],\[/g, '],\n['));
```

Yield:

```
[["album","artist","price"],
["str","str","num"],
[50,5,"50"],
[5,5,"5"],
["Lateralus","Tool","13"],
["Ænima","Tool","12"],
["10,000 days","Tool",14]]
```